# Factorial de un numero mayor a 12 equivocado en c++

Tags: c++

**Hola alguien sabe porque sucede que al calcular el factorial de cualquier numero menor o igual a 12 el resultado es el correcto pero al ingresar un numero mayor a 12, ejemplo el 13 su resultado es erróneo**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n, res = 1;

    cout<<"Ingrese digito para calcular su factorial: ";
    cin>>n;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n ; i++) {
    
       res *= i;
    
    }

    cout<<"\nEl factorial de "<<n<<" es:"<<res;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando n es mayor o igual a 13 se presenta un overflow. Esto quiere decir que el espacio que puede almacenar un entero no es suficiente, por lo que empezarás a obtener resultados incorrectos.

Más específicamente, el valor más grande que puede almacenar un entero es `2^31 - 1`. Por lo que un *int* utiliza 4 bytes (32 bits) y uno de esos bits se utiliza para el signo.

13! > 2^31 - 1

Si quieres computar factoriales más grandes puedes usar `long long`. El cual utiliza 8 bytes.

**Nota**: El tamaño depende de la arquitectura del sistema. Aunque este es el caso para la mayoría de sistemas de 32 y 64 bits.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por la explicación, tu respuesta fue muy útil